# How to again fetch the content of file which is copied from other file

Tags: c

I have removed unnecessary blank space from one(a.c) file and copied into other file(b.c).
Now i want to read the content of b.c which gives unexpected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  FILE* fr, *fw;
  char ch;
  fr = fopen("a.c", "r");

  if (!fr)
    printf("a.c not found");

  fw = fopen("b.c", "w");

  if (!fw)
    printf("b.c not found");

  while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {
    fputc(ch, fw);

    if (ch == ' ') {
      while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) == ' ') {
      }

      fputc(ch, fw);
    }
  }

  fclose(fr);
  fclose(fw);
  fr = fopen("b.c", "r");

  if (!fr)
    printf("b.c file not found");

  while (ch = fgetc(fr) != EOF)
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}
```

Comment: I think the c++ tag is not really relevant here

Comment: `ch = fgetc(fr) != EOF` is evaluated as `ch = (fgetc(fr) != EOF)`, change it to `(ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF`. You even do this correctly further up...

Comment: and `char ch;` --> `int ch;` and Space within a string literal is also converted. E.g `char data[] = "    ";` -->  `char data[] = " ";`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'Unnecessary spaces', i consider all the spaces in the source code.

You should not call fputc (ch, fw) as soon as  you read the character from file.

If you remove this, it will work. Below is the modified code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fr,*fw;
    char ch;
    fr=fopen("a.c","r");
    if(!fr)
         printf("a.c not found");
    fw=fopen("b.c","w");
   if(!fw)
    printf("b.c not found");
    while( (ch=fgetc(fr))!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch== ' ')
        {
            while( (ch=fgetc(fr))== ' '){
            }

        }
        fputc(ch,fw);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    fclose(fw);
    fr=fopen("b.c","r");
    if(!fr)
    printf("b.c file not found");
    while(ch=fgetc(fr)!=EOF)
            printf("%c\n",ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of fgetc is:

`int fgetc(FILE *stream);`

You must replace the `char ch;` with `int ch;`

The reason is that `fgetc()` reads the next character from stream and returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or EOF on end of file or error.You should not convert the value returned by a character I/O function to `char` if it returns `int` and that value will be compared to EOF. Once the return value of these functions has been converted to a `char` type, character values may be indistinguishable from `EOF`, which may lead to an infinite loop in your case.

Additionally,

```
while (ch = fgetc(fr) != EOF)
```

Should be

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF)
```

Because `!=` has higher precedence that of `=` and to do `ch=fgetc(fr)` first, you must enclose it in parentheses.

Algorithm fix:

```
  while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {
    fputc(ch, fw);

    if (ch == ' ') {
      while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) == ' ') {
      }

      fputc(ch, fw);
    }
  }
```

should be

```
while( (ch=fgetc(fr))!=EOF)
{
    if(ch== ' ')
        while( (ch=fgetc(fr))== ' ');
    fputc(ch,fw);
}
```

you must `fputc` only after you have checked for and traversed all the spaces in the line, between two non-space chars.

Now, your program would work well.